# where is module directory in laravel

Tags: codeigniter, laravel

In `CodeIgniter` framework there is a `module` directory :

```
application\models
```

but where is this directory in `laravel 5` framework ?

Comment: Don't think this answer should be down voted. It's an honest question that would even have some experienced PHP devs scratching their heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have one. Most people put models in the `app` folder itself, i.e. `App\User`. If you don't like that, just make a folder called `Models` and put them there.

Comment: I think It is fun !

Answer (score -2):

Laravel 5 doesn't have any model directory because laravel is not MVC framework.
Please refer laravel forum following url:
http://laravel.io/forum/10-26-2014-laravel-5-where-is-the-models-folder

Comment: This statement could come out in the wrong way: Laravel certainly separates view, controller and model, so it is an MVC framework in that sense. However, you are not limited in the details of that meaning that you can put your models whereever you would want them to be